# Unity Android: How can I ensure quality on splash image display?

Tags: android, textures, resolution, unity-game-engine, splash-screen

How can I ensure that the splash screen image in my Unity Android project is excellent at all resolutions?

Since Unity only allows me to specify one texture to use as a splash screen, and since Android devices come in a variety of resolutions, the texture will have to scale up or down to fit the screen.  Unfortunately, Unity's downscaling produces a chunky-looking low quality result on screens that are lower resolution than the image.  On the other hand, images smaller than the screen resolution scale up well, but are of course more fuzzy and anti-aliased due to their lower resolution.

Is there perhaps a way to alter the splash screen display at the Android OS level, or some other solution for this issue?

Thank you,
Bill

Answer (score 1):

If you can you can try converting your splash image into a 9 patch.

[9 patch tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)

[9 patch guide](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/)

I hope it helps..